# CSV output to Google Sheets is broken

Tags: excel, csv, google-sheets

I have a massive coffee database I'm adjusting into the same database for different cities based on different weather, cultural preferences for types of coffee, etc.  I am working in Google Colab.

Here's a row of my data: [CSV](https://github.com/tolky001/csvsample/blob/main/StackOverflow.csv).  I then convert to floats (just for January as a sample)

```
convert_dict = {'Jan': float,
            }
df3a = df3a.astype(convert_dict)
print(df3a.dtypes)
```

I then multiply by a scalar:

```
df3a['Jan'] *= .85
```

Then, I insert a column for the monthly number of daily visitors:

```
df3a.insert(1, 'DailyCustomersJan', '328')
```

change it into a float,

```
df3a = df3a.astype({'DailyCustomersJan':'float',})
print(df3a.dtypes)
```

create a divisor,

```
df3a["JanDivisor"] = df3a["DailyCustomersJan"]/df3a["Jan"]
```

and, now, this is the tricky part, try to create a formula that I can cut and paste into Excel.

```
df3a['JanDivisor'] = "=G2/" + df3a['JanDivisor'].astype(str)
```

Finally,

```
df3a.to_csv('JanDivisor.csv')
```

And everything goes haywire.

And I just realized that Mark fixed my problem.  The issue for some reason is that not setting index = false in writing the date frame to a CSV, when I added in an = in the string, caused the problem.  The correct code would have been

```
df3a.to_csv('JanDivisor.csv', index = False)
```

Here is the correctly outputted [CSV](https://github.com/tolky001/csvsample/blob/main/JanDivisorCorrect.csv) now.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the '='? If you are trying to apply Excel calculation- this will not work in Pandas

Comment: Dear gtomer:

I am trying to export into a CSV (outside of Pandas) and then cut and paste from the CSV into Google Sheets, saving a lot of time from having to input the formulas manually, about 90% of the time.  The puzzling thing is that it's just a string in Pandas, so you'd think it would be fine.  It's for a coffee database.

Comment: Hi Mark! Welcome to StackOverflow. I can't reproduce this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your results. This is what I did:

```
import pandas as pd

df9 = pd.DataFrame({
                     'JanDivisor': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],   
})

df9['JanDivisor'] = "=G2/" + df9['JanDivisor'].astype(str)

# write df9 to csv
df9.to_csv('df9.csv', index=False)
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AfLfYaMS6NQ_9BqFnFN9cIXj1nx1TRTWiGVRQB4BKlQ/edit?usp=sharing) is the resulting CSV imported into Google Sheets. It works fine.

Comment: Dear Mark:  

Thanks so much.  I have now edited to clarify this complicated problem and would love more feedback.

Best,

Mark

Comment: if you want to set my answer as the correct one, I think you can on your end!

Comment: @MarkAndrewHamilton Re:feedback- it looks quite good! I'll have another look in the morning and see if I missed anything

Comment: Thanks, I set it as the correct answer.  I also added in the exact issue into your answer, but please feel free to edit or delete as you see fit.